# Adding props to a component passed as a prop

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a list of items. My parent component defines the renderItem component to be used.

Is it possible for me to pass additional props to this component?

```
<Route exact path="/users/:uid/clients" component={Clients} />

const ParentComponent = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <Component
      renderItem={SimpleCard}
    />
  );
};


// Component

  ...

  renderList = list => {
    const RenderItem = this.props.renderItem;
    return list.map(item => {
      return <RenderItem item={item} />;
    });
  }; // BUSTED
```

The rendered RenderItem (aka SimpleCard) component never receives the "item" prop, it's undefined.

```
// SimpleCard
export default function SimpleCard({ item, onClick}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card} onClick={() => onClick(item)}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {item && item.name}
          </Typography>
          {item && item.description && (
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              {item && item.description}
            </Typography>
          )}
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>

      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => onClick(item)}>
          Details
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/z648nukh/4/ You might want to post the code for `SimpleCard` as well. I used a placeholder for the moment.

Comment: How you have called `renderList `?

Comment: It has suddenly started working... Thank you for the help everyone, I'm not sure why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i believe that is possible the same way you can do a render with `react-router` where you render a component to pass props like this

```
<Route path="/somepath/" component={MyComponent} />
<Route path="/someotherpath/" render={() => <MyOtherComponent props={"coolprop"}
```

you should be able to do the same kind of syntax like this

```
  <Component
      renderItem={<SimpleCard props={...props}/>}
    />
```

if this syntax does not work you will have to add

```
  <Component
   {...props}
      renderItem={SimpleCard}
    />
```

to pass the props down to the child component

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can pass as you want in the props for the component if it is more that one props used {...props}

```
<Component {...props} renderItem={other component}/>
```